# Cannot apply scale to a multiuser

Tags: scale

Why can't I apply scale to an object that has been instanced?

I mean: just apply it as the same to all the instances, no?

I forget to apply scale, then instanced the object 20 times, position it well and rotate it, and then I discover that it needs a small retouch that needs to be done in scale 1,1,1.

Comment: You cannot apply scale to multiuser because they can have different scales. Why don't you scale the object in edit mode?

Comment: Yes, as Carlo says.  If these are instanced they are all the same mesh.  Make a change to the mesh itself and it is done everywhere.

Comment: If you need to change a single one's mesh, duplicate it in place, and then delete the instanced version.

Comment: @Carlo I need to apply the scale because I need to add a modifier that works badly in different scale than 1,1,1.

Comment: @AllenSimpson that's not the point. The point is that in some cases it's **needed** to apply the 1,1,1 scale to one object or all the objects, so a feature in this direction would be useful.

Comment: What about the other object's scale? Doesn't it matter to your scopes? I mean, if you scaled the instance object's diffently, wouldn't this scale applying mess things up? You are not considering other object's scale in your argument.

Comment: Are your object's all with the same scale? You only rotate/repositioned them? Because if this is the case there's a simple solution to that. Please post a picture of the situation an add more info about your needs.

Comment: @Carlo well yes, in this case all the objects were only translated and rotated. They all have the same scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clear the scale of all the objects and scale in edit mode

Object's transformations are a powerful tool that allow animators to give variance to their meshes without affecting the basemesh itself and take advantage of instancings greater performance.

Usually intanced objects have different rotation, position and scale, so applying one of these would only mess up your scene. If you don't trust me , you can try duplicating the object, apllying the scale and use the resulting mesh data as input for the instanced object.

If, as in your case, you **didn't change the scale** of your instanced objects, you can simply *Clear the scale* of all the instances with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then scale one of the object in edit mode back to the previous value.

[image]